# Need help linking navigation pages to navigation bar (Windows Forms/DevExpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm working through the following tutorial:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116628/Build-an-Application/Choose-Application-UI/Office-Inspired-UI/How-to-Build-an-Office-inspired-UI-manually

I've achieved the desired output at step 8 (linking the office navigation bar and navigation bar controls), but I'm having trouble achieving the desired output at step 10 (changing the navigation page to display the different labels depending on the selected navigation bar group).

Here's my Form1.Designer.cs:

```
namespace dev_express_again
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.navigationFrame1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationFrame();
                this.navigationPage1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPage();
                this.labelControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
                this.navigationPage2 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPage();
                this.labelControl2 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
                this.navBarControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarControl();
                this.navBarGroup1 = new DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroup();
                this.navBarGroup2 = new DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroup();
                this.officeNavigationBar1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.OfficeNavigationBar();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.navigationFrame1)).BeginInit();
                this.navigationFrame1.SuspendLayout();
                this.navigationPage1.SuspendLayout();
                this.navigationPage2.SuspendLayout();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.navBarControl1)).BeginInit();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.officeNavigationBar1)).BeginInit();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // navigationFrame1
                // 
                this.navigationFrame1.Controls.Add(this.navigationPage1);
                this.navigationFrame1.Controls.Add(this.navigationPage2);
                this.navigationFrame1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 0);
                this.navigationFrame1.Name = "navigationFrame1";
                this.navigationFrame1.Pages.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPageBase[] {
                this.navigationPage1,
                this.navigationPage2});
                this.navigationFrame1.SelectedPage = this.navigationPage1;
                this.navigationFrame1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(462, 311);
                this.navigationFrame1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.navigationFrame1.Text = "navigationFrame1";
                // 
                // navigationPage1
                // 
                this.navigationPage1.Caption = "navigationPage1";
                this.navigationPage1.Controls.Add(this.labelControl1);
                this.navigationPage1.Name = "navigationPage1";
                this.navigationPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(462, 311);
                this.navigationPage1.Tag = "Employees";
                // 
                // labelControl1
                // 
                this.labelControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 145);
                this.labelControl1.Name = "labelControl1";
                this.labelControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(33, 13);
                this.labelControl1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.labelControl1.Text = "Page 1";
                // 
                // navigationPage2
                // 
                this.navigationPage2.Caption = "navigationPage2";
                this.navigationPage2.Controls.Add(this.labelControl2);
                this.navigationPage2.Name = "navigationPage2";
                this.navigationPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(462, 311);
                this.navigationPage2.Tag = "Customers";
                // 
                // labelControl2
                // 
                this.labelControl2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(194, 135);
                this.labelControl2.Name = "labelControl2";
                this.labelControl2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(33, 13);
                this.labelControl2.TabIndex = 0;
                this.labelControl2.Text = "Page 2";
                // 
                // navBarControl1
                // 
                this.navBarControl1.ActiveGroup = this.navBarGroup1;
                this.navBarControl1.Groups.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroup[] {
                this.navBarGroup1,
                this.navBarGroup2});
                this.navBarControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                this.navBarControl1.Name = "navBarControl1";
                this.navBarControl1.OptionsNavPane.ExpandedWidth = 140;
                this.navBarControl1.PaintStyleKind = DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarViewKind.NavigationPane;
                this.navBarControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 311);
                this.navBarControl1.TabIndex = 1;
                this.navBarControl1.Text = "navBarControl1";
                // 
                // navBarGroup1
                // 
                this.navBarGroup1.Caption = "Employees";
                this.navBarGroup1.Expanded = true;
                this.navBarGroup1.Name = "navBarGroup1";
                // 
                // navBarGroup2
                // 
                this.navBarGroup2.Caption = "Customers";
                this.navBarGroup2.Name = "navBarGroup2";
                // 
                // officeNavigationBar1
                // 
                this.officeNavigationBar1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
                this.officeNavigationBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 317);
                this.officeNavigationBar1.Name = "officeNavigationBar1";
                this.officeNavigationBar1.NavigationClient = this.navBarControl1;
                this.officeNavigationBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(608, 45);
                this.officeNavigationBar1.TabIndex = 2;
                this.officeNavigationBar1.Text = "officeNavigationBar1";
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(608, 362);
                this.Controls.Add(this.officeNavigationBar1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.navBarControl1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.navigationFrame1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Form1";
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.navigationFrame1)).EndInit();
                this.navigationFrame1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.navigationPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.navigationPage1.PerformLayout();
                this.navigationPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.navigationPage2.PerformLayout();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.navBarControl1)).EndInit();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.officeNavigationBar1)).EndInit();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.PerformLayout();

            }

            #endregion

            private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationFrame navigationFrame1;
            private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPage navigationPage1;
            private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPage navigationPage2;
            private DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarControl navBarControl1;
            private DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroup navBarGroup1;
            private DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroup navBarGroup2;
            private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.OfficeNavigationBar officeNavigationBar1;
            private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl labelControl1;
            private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl labelControl2;
        }
    }
```

And my Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dev_express_again
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            navigationPage1.Tag = navBarGroup1.Caption = navigationPage1.Caption = "Employees";
            navigationPage2.Tag = navBarGroup2.Caption = navigationPage2.Caption = "Customers";

            officeNavigationBar1.NavigationClient = navBarControl1;
        }

        private void navBarControl1_ActiveGroupChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroupEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationFrame1.SelectedPage = (DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.NavigationPage)navigationFrame1.Pages.FindFirst(x => (string)x.Tag == e.Group.Caption);
        }
    }
}
```

Both are exactly the same as the tutorial, as far as I can see. When I run the code, I get a window that looks exactly like the one in the tutorial. When I change the selection in the office navigation bar, it reflects in the navigation bar control, but does not change the navigation page.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. The tutorial neglected to mention that you also must add the line `navBarControl1.ActiveGroupChanged += new DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarGroupEventHandler(navBarControl1_ActiveGroupChanged);` to Form1.cs in order to enable the user's changing of the active group to actually call the `navBarControl1_ActiveGroupChanged` function.

Comment: This point is clearly mentioned at step 9: _Handle the NavBarControl.ActiveGroupChanged event to switch the selected Frame page._ ;-)